# Random pixels and stripes on screen while booting, disappear in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, graphics-card

My lcd started showing random patterns of rgb pixels all over the screen. This is visible only at certain resolutions. It is visible during boot and in bios. It is OK when the windows logo is displayed while booting.

However, it changes to white vertical stripes when windows logon screen is displayed. Subsequently Windows locks up when password is entered on the logon screen and needs to be forcefully rebooted.

However, windows boots into safe mode and the patterns do not appear at any resolution in safe mode. Also after uninstalling the gpu drivers while in safe mode and restarting windows, it disappears, but windows then detects the "new" hw and installs drivers and all is back to malfunctioning.

It is always visible in bios and while booting, therefore it is not driver related.

I suspect this is hw failure and I am getting my gpu replaced, but is there an explanation for the fact that it happens in bios and does not happen in safe mode or while windows is using some fallback driver, or while windows logo is displayed during boot?

Ati Radeon X1950 GT.

Update: now it booted into windows and I could verify that a printscreen screenshot captures all the strange patterns. 30 seconds after booting into Windows, BSOD appeared with BAD_POOL_HEADER. On another attempt, IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely sounds like a hardware failure. The reason that you saw artifacts during BIOS and not in safe mode may just be you weren't using the failing portion. With the default VGA driver, not all of the stream processors or memory might have been available for use. However, your BIOS video drivers may have utilized that failing portion.

Comment: Yes, this was a hardware failure. Replacing the card helped